# CodeModel How do i add @Pattern.List annotations com.sun.codemodel

Tags: java, bean-validation, sun-codemodel

I'm using com.sun.codemodel for generating my classes and adding JSR303 annotations. This is working fine, except when I want to add @Pattern.List annotations.

```
field.annotate(Pattern.class).param("regexp", "some_expression");
```

This is currently what is generated:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "first_expression", message = "first.Pattern.message")
@Pattern(regexp = "second_expression", message = "second.Pattern.message")
@Pattern(regexp = "third_expression", message = "third.Pattern.message")
```

This is what I want to be generated

```
@Pattern.List({
  @Pattern(regexp = "first_expression", message = "first.Pattern.message")
  @Pattern(regexp = "second_expression", message = "second.Pattern.message")
  @Pattern(regexp = "third_expression", message = "third.Pattern.message")
})
```

Somebody any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want @PatternList(list = {@Pattern...}) instead you need to use the `paramArray()` method:

```
JDefinedClass testme = codeModel._class("Testme");

JAnnotationUse patternListAnnotation = testme.annotate(Pattern.List.class);
JAnnotationArrayMember list = patternListAnnotation.paramArray("value");

list.annotate(Pattern.class).param("regexp", "first_expression").param("message", "first.Pattern.message");
list.annotate(Pattern.class).param("regexp", "second_expression").param("message", "second.Pattern.message");
list.annotate(Pattern.class).param("regexp", "third_expression").param("message", "third.Pattern.message");
```

Outputs the following:

```
@Pattern.List({
    @Pattern(regexp = "first_expression", message = "first.Pattern.message"),
    @Pattern(regexp = "second_expression", message = "second.Pattern.message"),
    @Pattern(regexp = "third_expression", message = "third.Pattern.message")
})
public class Testme {
}
```

This should work the same for fields as hinted in your example code.

Comment: Pattern.List is working fine in Java, your proposed solution is solving my problem, this is what I did:JAnnotationArrayMember fieldPatterns = field.annotate(Pattern.List.class).paramArray("value");

fieldPatterns.annotate(Pattern.class).param("regexp", "first_expression");
fieldPatterns.annotate(Pattern.class).param("regexp", "second_expression");
fieldPatterns.annotate(Pattern.class).param("regexp", "third_expression");

Comment: Not really anything to share, the Pattern and Pattern.List interfaces are defined in the javax.validation 1.0 API

See

 - javax.validation.constraints.Pattern   
 - javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.List

I'm currently using the Hibernate implementation.

Comment: Cool.  I have just never come across this particular annotation syntax before.  Thanks!